# I dont want to redefine properties when defining a GraphQL type. Is there a way to get past it?

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

principal

```
interface Community {
  uuid: String
  name: String
  tagline: String
  desc: String
  location: String
}
```

his children

```
type CommunityWithOwnerUser implements Community {
  uuid: String
  name: String
  tagline: String
  desc: String
  location: String
  //....owner details
  ownerUuid:String
  ownerName:String
}
```

other child

```
type CommunityWithAnyMember implements Community {
  uuid: String
  name: String
  tagline: String
  desc: String
  location: String
  //....member details
  memberUuid:String
  memberName:String
}
```

I know that these types are unreasonable.it is example

my question

I've rewritten the details of the `Community` type in all type definitions. instead it would be great if I could use something like `extend`

```
type CommunityWithAnyMember extend Community {
  memberUuid:String
  memberName:String
}
```

its output

```
type CommunityWithAnyMember {
  uuid: String
  name: String
  tagline: String
  desc: String
  location: String
  memberUuid:String
  memberName:String
}
```

I've been doing research for a long time.
I found https://github.com/Sydsvenskan/node-graphql-partials but it didn't help.Thank you for your answer

Comment: Also see this answer for a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940240/using-graphql-fragment-on-multiple-types/48940648#48940648

Comment: thanks @DanielRearden. that helped

Comment: Since this question is a duplicate, feel free to delete it and upvote any helpful answers for the two questions above.