# GraphQL fragment of fragments

Tags: javascript, graphql

I have a GraphQL query like this:

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

export default gql`
  {
    pageHomeCollection(limit: 1) {
      items {
        navigationLinkLeft {
          ... on PageBasic {
            slug
            title
          }
          ... on PageShop {
            title
          }
          ... on PostCollection {
            slug
            title
          }
        }
        navigationLinkRight {
          ... on PageBasic {
            slug
            title
          }
          ... on PageShop {
            title
          }
          ... on PostCollection {
            slug
            title
          }
        }
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

The requested data for both `navigationLinkLeft` and `navigationLinkRight` are the same, so I'd like to avoid the duplication. I know about fragments, but not sure if it's possible to extract the 3 `... on` because I'm not sure what type the fragment would be. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using GraphQL Fragment on multiple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940240/using-graphql-fragment-on-multiple-types)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can nest fragments. Assuming `navigationLinkLeft` and `navigationLinkRight` have the same type, you can do something like this:

```
{
  pageHomeCollection(limit: 1) {
    items {
    navigationLinkLeft {
      ...YourFragment
    }
    navigationLinkRight {
      ...YourFragment
    }
    title
  }
}

fragment YourFragment on SomeInterfaceOrUnionType {
  ... on PageBasic {
    slug
    title
  }
  ... on PageShop {
    title
  }
  ... on PostCollection {
    slug
    title
  }
}
```

If `navigationLinkLeft` and `navigationLinkRight` do **not** have the same type, this won't work. At best, you can only avoid duplicating the fields themselves:

```
{
  pageHomeCollection(limit: 1) {
    items {
    navigationLinkLeft {
      ...NavigationLinkLeftFragment
    }
    navigationLinkRight {
      ...NavigationLinkRightFragment
    }
    title
  }
}

fragment NavigationLinkLeftFragment on PageHomeNavigationLinkLeft {
  ...PageBasicFragment
  ...PageShopFragment
  ...PostCollectionFragment
}

fragment NavigationLinkRightFragment on NavigationLinkRight {
  ...PageBasicFragment
  ...PageShopFragment
  ...PostCollectionFragment
}

fragment PageBasicFragment on PageBasic {
  slug
  title
}

fragment PageShopFragment on PageShop {
  title
}

fragment PostCollectionFragment on PostCollection {
  slug
  title
}
```

The above avoids using inline fragments, but you can always use an inline fragment if you don't need to reference a fragment by name elsewhere. So you can also just do:

```
navigationLinkLeft {
  ...PageBasicFragment
  ...PageShopFragment
  ...PostCollectionFragment
}
navigationLinkRight {
  ...PageBasicFragment
  ...PageShopFragment
  ...PostCollectionFragment
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So I figured you could do this but wasn't sure what `SomeInterfaceOrUnionType` would need to be in this case. Each of the 3 things in the fragment are their own types.

Comment: @Coop you need to check the schema you're querying to determine what the type is for the `navigationLinkLeft` field. If you didn't write the schema yourself, you can check the docs in GraphiQL or GraphQL Playground, or use introspection.

Comment: Righty. So GraphiQL is telling me the 3 potential datasets on navigationLeftLink are of type `PageHomeNavigationLinkLeft` and the 3 on navigationLinkRight are of type `NavigationLinkRight`. So is it still possible to achieve what I want when the types are different?

Comment: @Coop Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. If the types are different, then, no you won't be able to do DRY things up as much. Please see my edit.