# How to use composition in Typegraphql

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

Im using typeorm and typegraphql to build an API and I would like to abstract out properties of an entity into separate files and then import them to clean up the file:

Example of current

```
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class Person extends BaseEntity {
  @Field()
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  surname: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  age: number;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  email: string;
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
class Name {
  @Field()
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  surname: string;
}
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class Person extends BaseEntity {
  @Field()
  @Column()
  age: number;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  email: string;

  // then import the class here 
  ...Name
}
```

Is there any way to do this without creating separate entities and tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using mixins to solve this because embedded entities doesn't work with both typeorm and typegraphql

```
export const WithName = <SubClass extends Constructor>(subClass?: SubClass) => {
  @ObjectType({ isAbstract: true })
  @InputType({ isAbstract: true })
  class Mixin extends getFallbackClass(subClass) {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
    }
    @Field()
    @Column()
    first: string;

    @Field()
    @Column()
    second: string;

  }

  return Mixin;
};
```

then using it like:

```
class Human extends WithName(class {}) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible client side by using fragments https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/fragments/

Perhaps you can use something like type inheritance perhaps by using this library https://github.com/nicolasdao/graphql-s2s

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940240/using-graphql-fragment-on-multiple-types) for reference.

Comment: Ended up using mixins